# How is the standard deviation of VAE's obtained?

Tags: probability, autoencoder, gaussian

I am trying to build a Variational Autoencoder. I was looking at various codes online and found most of them in some way or another copy Francois Chollet (Google researchers) [code](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).

Now my main question with this code is this part:

[image]

As you can clearly see the $log(\sigma)$ is the output from a Dense layer. Where did this assumption come from (the output is $log(\sigma)$ and not $\sigma$? How is it possible that we generate a random normal distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$ like this? Is it due to the way the computer generates Normal Distributions?

Comment: @Esmailian you can see that K_log_sigma = dense(latent_dim) which is the same as z_mean taken in the above line

Comment: @Esmailian ok sorry..i'll edit that part out but the question will now be why is it $log(\sigma)$ and not $\sigma$